# how does php class instantiation of solarium work behind the scene?

Tags: php, solarium

So the specifics of my question are about Solarium. I want to know how php can figure out which class you mean without including the specific class file.

Why does the line

```
$client = new Solarium\Client($config);
```

create a new client object? How is this different than including the php file directly and tryint to do

```
$client = new Client($config);
```

Im coming from Java and I dont quite understand how php figures things out behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

PHP itself (language/engine) doesn't care at all how do you divide your code into files. You could even keep everything in single file, but you will admit, that it is not the best idea. PHP doesn't provide general/default way of autoloading files based on the classes names, as there is no default structure.

It provides instead a [callback mechanism](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), which allows you to include some file, when PHP has been asked for using a class, which is not yet define. And then you can use any structure for your project.

Of course there would be a mess, so community introduced some [standard here](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

So, answering your question. There is no difference really. The result is the same for both snippets presented by you. It just works in different way than Java, thus may be a bit confusing. There is no strict, forced relation between classes and files, but we have some rules, which we try to follow to avoid problems.